# "Parent" is to "child" as "source" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

I have a work question. In our attempt to give names to fields on a repair card we are now using the phrase "Source card" and "Child card".
My opinion is that it would be more logical to use "Parent card" and "Child card", but if I want to keep using the term "Source card" how would I now name the child card???

> "Parent is related to child"
>   as
>   "source is related to _____"

Comment: Welcome to ELU. As you are posting a single-word-request I edited your question. Have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out about posting good questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because naming things in a non-sentence context if off-topic.

Comment: Helmar, thanks for the welcome message and editing of my question :-)

Comment: source is often related to sink in sciency things, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source%E2%80%93sink_dynamics and graph theory for example.

Comment: Programmatically we call it "output", source is related to "output" as parent-child relation.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you say whether a source can have more than one XXX, and whether a XXX can have more than one source.

Comment: In your context, what makes a "source card" related to *source* or *parent*? Likewise for the other card.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different possibilities:

- **source and *target***

  These two words are often paired together in the context of (for example) databases; see e.g. [What is a source table, and a target table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22087/what-is-a-source-table-and-a-target-table) on another SE.
- **source and *sink***

  As [mentioned in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344537/source-is-related-to#comment796548_344537) , these two words are often paired together in the context of (for example) dynamics; see e.g. [Source-sink dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source%E2%80%93sink_dynamics) at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

***derivative***

From Wiktionary:

> *Noun*
> **[derivative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derivative)** ‎(plural derivates)
>
> Something derived.
>
> *Adjective* [**derived**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derived) ‎(not comparable)
>
> product of derivation
>
> The French language is derived from Latin.
>
> *Noun*
> **[derivation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derivation)**
>
> The act of receiving anything from a source; the act of procuring an
> effect from a cause, means, or condition, as profits from capital,
> conclusions or opinions from evidence.
>
> The state or method of being derived; the relation of origin when
> established or asserted.
>
> That which is derived; a derivative; a deduction.